# WPF textbox height before its rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, height

How can you the get actual height of a textbox before rendering the object
in wpf?

The following code will work in windows but in WPF what is the equivalent ?

```
textBox1.Text = "Test";  
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");  
float FontLineSpacing = fontFamily.GetLineSpacing(FontStyle.Regular);  

// Get the em height of the font family in design units.  
int emHeight = fontFamily.GetEmHeight(FontStyle.Regular);  
var Height = (textBox1.Font.Size * FontLineSpacing / emHeight) + 7;
```

Comment: I've edited your question - please use clean language next time and avoid using repetitive question marks, it helps no one.

Comment: Are you trying to get the size of the text? Or the size of the textbox?

Comment: If it's the height of the `TextBox` then `textBox1.ActualHeight` is what you want.

Comment: thanks Shai, i need actual height of textbox but before rendering on canvas or grid. textBox1.ActualHeight works, but after drawing or rendering it, not before.

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke `UpdateLayout()` method of the element before accessing its `ActualHeight`.

For example txtBlock.UpdateLayout().